# Laravel Blade Directives not executing when template loaded from string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**EDIT**: The code snippet below, where `view` takes an array `['template' => 'my template']` as the first argument is a feature of `wpb/string-blade-compiler` which is overriding the native laravel functionality.

I have a directive registered in `AppServiceProvider::boot`:

```
public function boot()
{
    Blade::directive('hello', function($expression) {
        return "<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>";
    });
}
```

It works perfectly when I use file based templates saved as `resources/views/something.blade.php` and used `return view('something', $data)` in my `Controller::action`.

However when I try:

```
try {
  return view(['template' => $template], $data)->render();
} catch(\ErrorException $ex) {
  preg_match('/Undefined variable: (.+?)\s/', $ex->getMessage(), $matches);
  if ($matches) {
    return sprintf('Template: variable {{ $%s }} is invalid', $matches[1]);
  }
  return sprintf('%s: %s', $attribute, $ex->getMessage());
}
```

And try and use templates from a string, the directive isn't loaded. No errors, no nothing.

Does anyone with an intimate knowledge of laravel know the difference with these two contexts? I would have thought they'd yield the same result but do not. I'm struggling to understand the laravel architecture to unravel this one. Thanks.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.2",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
    "sofa/eloquence": "^5.2",
    "wpb/string-blade-compiler": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^3.0"
}
```

PHP 5.6

Comment: Have you tried using `View::make()` instead?

Comment: @Derek, yup. Both yield same results = working view, less my directive.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @Derek, added snippet from composer.json above.

Comment: Alright, I did some testing and I believe I may have the answer you want, posting answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I did a little testing on my own server and came up with a solution:

My condensed code in a singe route:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {

    $template = Blade::compileString('@hello(derek) !');

    ob_start();

    try {

        eval('?>' . $template);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        ob_get_clean(); throw $e;

    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;

});
```

And the directive, if you care to see it:

```
public function boot()
    {
        //
        Blade::directive('hello', function($d) {

            return "<?php echo \"Hello {$d}\"; ?>";
        });
    }
```

There is like little to no documentation on this, so debugging could be a hassle, but I do know if you would like to pass in more variables to the string, it would look like this:

```
Route::get('/test2', function () {

    $args = ['name' => 'derek'];

    $template = Blade::compileString('@hello($name) !');

    ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    try {

        eval('?>' . $template);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        ob_get_clean(); throw $e;

    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;

});
```

Finally, a simple function you can place in your controller:

```
// way to call:

$this->strView('@hello($name)', ['name' => 'Tom Riddle']);

public function strView($view, $args) {
    $template = Blade::compileString($view);

    ob_start() and extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    try {

        eval('?>' . $template);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        ob_get_clean(); throw $e;

    }

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realise "wpb/string-blade-compiler" was overriding the default laravel behaviour that doesn't support strings. I need to edit the question to clarify this. Laravel doesn't support blade templates as strings. Natively it compiles vanilla php to a cache file and includes it. Your solution, using eval, is an alternative to writing files. Both use output buffering.

Comment: @Simon - with my solution, it returns the finished HTML - is this not what you were looking for?