# Use {{ }} inside {{!! !!}} in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am saving my blog post as HTML into the database. An entry would look like this

```
<article>
    <h2>Simple Method to add WhatsApp button to Shopify Manually &#8211; Hard Coding</h2> 
    <figure>
        <img width="1024" height="366" src="{{ asset('storage/posts/screenshot-1024x366.jpg') }}" />
    </figure>
</article>
```

I display this in my template as. `{!! $post->content !!}`

Problem: Image is not displaying. Instead of displaying the actual asset link. It displays the directive `{{ asset('storage/posts/whatsapp.jpg') }}`

How can I escape the blade curly brace syntax and print the actual URL in the blade?

I want `{{ asset('storage/posts/whatsapp.jpg') }}` to display as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/posts/whatsapp.jpg`

Comment: store url as it is instead of storing blade template in string content.So before printing in your template replace URL with `APP_URL`  or best way is to place placeholders so you can replace easily

Comment: Also, worth looking @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839080/laravel-blade-directives-not-executing-when-template-loaded-from-string

Comment: Write your html view from DB into a temporary blade file, render it and return output string to blade file you wish to send to the user - https://wyattblogs.com/posts/how-to-compile-a-string-using-laravel-blade